# portech mv-370 send SMS trough script

Tags: php, python, at-command, sms-gateway

I have PORTECH MV-370 ( http://www.portech.com.tw/p3-product1_1.asp?Pid=13 ) and I need to send SMS trough script (python, php, java or something else). Using AT-COMMANDS I've sent some SMS with successful. 
My problem is I don't have any response from portech mv-370 and sometimes do not start the SMS sending

If i use the web interface, all sms i send go with successful. 
With the script sometimes no.

```
        $xusername=SMS_USER_PORTECH;
        $xhost=SMS_HOST_PORTECH;
        $xpassword=SMS_PASS_PORTECH;

        $myoutput = "";
        $fp = fsockopen("$xhost", 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            return "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";

        }
        sleep(2);

        $cmd = "$xusername\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(1);

        $cmd = "$xpassword\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(1);

        $cmd = "module\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(2);

        $cmd = "ate1\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(1);

        $cmd = "AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(2);    

        //Select SMS Message Format... (0=PDU Mode, 1=Text Mode)
        $cmd = "at+cmgf=1\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        $myoutput .= fread($fp, 256);
        sleep(2);

        //Send SMS Message...
        $cmd = "at+cmgs=\"$address\"\r";
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        sleep(2);
        $myoutput .= fread($fp, 256);

        //Body...

        $cmd = "$xbody\r\x1a"; //Ctrl-Z
        fputs($fp, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        $res = " ";
        $myoutput = "";

        $info = stream_set_timeout($fp, 5); //5 seconds read timeout

        while ($res != "")
          { 
            $res = fread($fp, 256);
            $myoutput .= $res;
          }


        fclose($fp);
        if ($info['timed_out']) {
             $status=false;
        }
        else $status=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

You can send SMS in the language of your choice using one of these [helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries). My personal favorite is Python.

```
# Download the twilio-python library from http://twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Find these values at https://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(to="+12316851234", from_="+15555555555",
                                     body="Hello there!")
```

And if you need advice on bridging with Portech [check out this post](http://blog.gmc.uy/2014/03/a-restful-bridge-to-send-and-receive.html).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Megan, I dismiss my portech in favor this https://github.com/youngj/EnvayaSMS